# counting the number of columns in a row of a HTML table using selenium xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have to fetch the count of the columns present in a particular row using the selenium Xpath.
Following the code which I wrote for this:

```
 WebElement table = CoreCommands.locateElement(context, By.xpath("//table[@id='addRowTable_selected_a']"));
        if (table != null) {
            List<WebElement> ts_rows = CoreCommands.locateElementList(context, table,By.xpath("//table[@id='addRowTable_selected_a']/tbody/tr"));
            int ts_cntRows = ts_rows.size(); 


        for(int i=4;i<=ts_cntRows;i++)
        {

            List<WebElement> ts_cols = CoreCommands.locateElementList(context, table,By.xpath("//table[@id='addRowTable_selected_a']/tbody/tr[i]/td"));
            int ts_cntCols = ts_cols.size();

            for(int j=1;j<=ts_cntCols;j++)
            {
              String str= CoreCommands.locateElement(context, By.xpath("//table[@id='addRowTable_selected_a']/tbody/tr[i]/td[j]")).getText();
            System.out.println(str);


            }
        }
```

It is returning zero in ts_cntCols for any row.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with xpath used i hope.. Lets see in above used "//table[@id='addRowTable_selected_a']/tbody/tr[i]/td" which is nothing but string and not passing dynamic i value, correct? so try like below

```
   "//table[@id='addRowTable_selected_a']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td"
```

similarly do same for columns xpath also to get text.

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

An example counting the number of cells for each row from row 3:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables");

// iterate each row from row 3
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='table1']/tbody/tr[position() > 2]"));
for (WebElement row : rows) {

    // get all the cells from the row
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"));

    // print the number of columns
    System.out.printf("columns: %d%n", cells.size());

    // iterate each column
    for (WebElement cell : cells) {

        // print the content
        System.out.println(cell.getText());
    }
}

driver.quit();
```